# Assign results of apply to multiple columns of data frame

Tags: r, apply

I would like to process all rows in data frame `df` by applying function `f` to every row. As function `f` returns numeric vector with two elements I would like to assign individual elements to new columns in `df`.

Sample `df`, trivial function `f` returning two elements and my trial with using `apply`

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 3:5)

f <- function (a, b) {
  c(a + b, a * b)
}

df[, c('apb', 'amb')] <- apply(df, 1, function(x) f(a = x[1], b = x[2]))
```

This does not work results are assigned by columns:

```
> df
  a b apb amb
1 1 3   4   8
2 2 4   3   8
3 3 5   6  15
```

Comment: Are you aware that you can do it vectorized, i.e. without `apply`, like this: `df$apb <- df$a + df$b; df$amb <- df$a * df$b`?

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes, this is just toy example, my real function is much more complex - it is not trivial to split it into more functions/expressions returning individual elements.

Comment: Okay, I already thought that might be the case..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use `Reduce` instead of `apply` as it is generally more efficient. You just need to slightly modify your function to use `cbind` instead of `c`

```
f <- function (a, b) {
  cbind(a + b, a * b) # midified to use `cbind` instead of `c`
}

df[c('apb', 'amb')] <- Reduce(f, df)
df
#   a b apb amb
# 1 1 3   4   3
# 2 2 4   6   8
# 3 3 5   8  15
```

---

*Note*: This will only work nicely if you have only two columns (as in your example), thus if you have more columns in you data set, run this only on a subset

Comment: Nice "midified" approach :) +1

Answer (score 2):

You need to transpose `apply` results to get what you want :

```
df[, c('apb', 'amb')] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) f(a = x[1], b = x[2])))

> df
  a b apb amb
1 1 3   4   3
2 2 4   6   8
3 3 5   8  15
```